# k8s nginx-ingress route vpn vs non-vpn traffic separately

Tags: nginx, vpn, nginx-ingress

I have a (toy) kubernetes cluster with nginx for ingress. The cluster is accessible both over vpn as well as through the public internet. I want to restrict access for certain routes to vpn only. How can I do this?

So far, I only found one possible way: I could use an ip-whitelist to restrict access to only ip addresses on the vpn, like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 10.10.10.1/24 # this being the VPN range
```

But to be honest, this feels a bit hacky. I would expect that the proper way to do this would be restricting the network interface on which we accept ingress.

What is the proper way of doing this? Can we restrict the network interface on which we accept ingress for a given route? Or is whitelisting the source ip the right way to go  about this?